# Finding amount of maximum items at a time in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm trying out Django on my backend and currently have a reservation database schema that is similar to the following:

```
| Equipment id | Amount |   Starting time   |    Ending time
|      1       |   2    |  2021-09-21 12:30 | 2021-09-21 16:00
|      1       |   3    |  2021-09-21 15:00 | 2021-09-21 20:00
|      1       |   5    |  2021-09-21 18:00 | 2021-09-21 20:00
```

1)
I would have to calculate the amount of maximum equipments reserved at a certain time window, for example 17:00-21:00 should return 8. I tried to use `queryset.annotate(maxAmount=Sum(amount))` but it returns  in this case the sum of all equipments reserved in the queryset.

Could the possible solution be to group the reservations with overlapping time windows and then find out the greatest amount from that? What could be the command to group them that way?

2)
Kind of same problem, but I would also have to find the time windows where the amount of reserved equipments is less than a certain threshold.

Example with above data: I would want to find times where the amount of reserved equipments is less than 3: it should return 00:00 -> 12:30, 16:00 -> 18:00 and 20:00 -> 00:00.

EDIT: The code that I use for queryset generation:

```
def reservation_queryset(equipment_ids, starting_time, ending_time, time_between_res=0, id_to_ignore=None):
    '''Queryset for returning matching reservations, for reservation checks'''

    ### Get reservations that are ongoing at the time with time windows at ends
    # Reservations that start before this ends


    timequery = Q(starting_time__lt=ending_time + timedelta(minutes=time_between_res))


    # Reservations that end after this starts
    timequery.add(Q(ending_time__gt=starting_time - timedelta(minutes=time_between_res)), Q.AND)

    # Exclude the given reservation
    equipmentquery = ~Q(id=id_to_ignore)

    # Select the reservation equipments
    equipmentquery.add(Q(equipments__equipment__in=equipment_ids), Q.AND)

    # Combine the queries
    fullquery = timequery
    fullquery.add(equipmentquery, Q.AND)

    # Apply the filter as distinct and get the queryset
    existing_reservations = models.Reservation.objects.filter(fullquery).distinct()

    return existing_reservations
```

EDIT #2:
And here is the code I currently have used to find the maximum amount of equipments:

````
def get_reserved_equipments(queryset):
    '''Returns a object with amounts of reserved equipments in the given queryset.'''

    values = queryset.prefetch_related('equipments').values('equipments__equipment')
    reserved_equipments = values.annotate(amount=Sum('equipments__amount'))
    return reserved_equipments```
````

Comment: Hi Late! Would you mind showing some code to your specific problem please!

Comment: Hi David! I added the creation of my queryset, it uses some many-to-many -relations but in the end creates a queryset of same structure as in my original question

Comment: It will be easier if you have separate rows for start_time and end_time. Then you can read in all data for a particular equipment id ordered chronologically, and iterate through them incrementing a counter for every row type "start" and decrementing it for every row type "ending".

Comment: That could work, even though it increases the amount of rows by 2 for every reservation, which of course increases pressure on the database. Thanks, I'll give it a look and try what I can achieve

Answer (score 0):

> I would have to calculate the amount of maximum equipments reserved at
>   a certain time window

I guess [annotate with filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations) is what you need

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Q

qs_with_annotate = queryset.values('filed_with_equipment_id').annotate(amount_sum_17_21=Sum('amount', filter=Q(starting_time__hour__gte = 17) & Q(ending_time__hour__lt = 21))
```

after this you can aggregate Max

```
from django.db.models import Max

max_sum = qs_with_annotate.aggregate(max_sum = Max('amount_sum_17_21'))['max_sum']
```

and filter, to get max `filed_with_equipment_id`

```
qs_with_annotate.filter(amount_sum_17_21 = max_sum)
```